# Can't change name after adding 'color' in Minecraft PE?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I changed my Minecraft PE name, I added color from the new update. However, it wouldn't let me enter worlds, so I tried to retype my name without color.

Now I can't type or use my name at all, and I can only talk with signs and am unable join other worlds.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you edit your question and give us more information? What do you mean by "adding color for the update?" Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the days, but it's still that way! The ways to solve this is:

1. Wait until the updates comes and maybe they will fix this bug!
2. Delete the game and install it again, but I tried it and my world disabled.
3. Report this bug to the Notch's development AB.

These are all ways you can fix it.